# Creating heat map animation based on point-shapefile with data attribute in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, modis, heat-map, animation

I want to create an animation of forest fires, using the NASA' MODIS data for the last 11 years. Their shapefile has acquisition data attribute — and it goes day by day all those years.

I've already tried to create an animation based on points only — looks good, but not so perfect and representative as heat maps could be.

So what I want to do is to create day by day animation (at least for one year, just for the start), but transforming these points to the heat maps and get the whole animation.

What advices can you give?

Maybe there's some drill with arcpy code that I can do?

Or there are other off-code algorithms to deal with?

Comment: What kind of heatmap are you looking for? Examples here: https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000012211

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your requirements I would suggest you to use kernel-density: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/kernel-density.htm